# How to enable first tab selected by default in this javascript?

Tags: javascript

The code creates 3 content tabs how to make the first tab selected by default when the page loads and after that, it should function as expected. The user should be able to click on any other tab but at the beginning, the first tab should be opened by default.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">London</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Paris</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tokyo</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would do it with classes and add and remove classes. So by default, you just have the class on the element you want to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to **add** the `selected class` in the html for the first tab and remove `display:none` from corresponding details pane.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding w3-border-red">London</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Paris</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tokyo</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```